# Why Is BuiltStatement more efficient than BoundStatement in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

[This link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/statements/) says:

> BoundStatement: obtained by binding values to a prepared statement. Typically used for queries that are executed often, with different values.
>   BuiltStatement: a statement built with the QueryBuilder DSL. It can be executed directly like a simple statement, or prepared.

So in my opinion, BuiltStatement is equal to BoundStatement.
Howerver, in my case, I found BuiltStatement is obviously more efficient than BoundStatement. Why did this happen?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Data mc = null;
        ResultSet results = null;
        PK pk = null;
        CassandraData dao = new CassandraData();
        Session session = dao.getSession();
        long start, end;
        long start0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
//      PreparedStatement prepared = session.prepare(
//              "select * from test where E=? and D=? and M=?");
        Statement statement = null;
        logger.info("Start:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            pk = ValidData.getOnePk();
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();

//          statement = prepared.bind(pk.E, pk.D, pk.M);
//          statement.setReadTimeoutMillis(100000);

            statement = getSelect(pk);

            results = session.execute(statement);
            end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            logger.info("Show OneKb:" + (end - start) / 1000.0 + "s.");
        }

        long end0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.info("Show OneKb Average:" + (end0 - start0) / 1000.0 / 100 + "s/OneKb.");
    }

    private static Statement getSelect(PK pk) {
        Select ss = QueryBuilder.select().from("test");
        ss.setConsistencyLevel(com.datastax.driver.core.ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
        ss.where(QueryBuilder.eq("E", pk.E))
                .and(QueryBuilder.eq("D", pk.D))
                .and(QueryBuilder.eq("M", pk.M)).limit(1)
                .setReadTimeoutMillis(100 * 1000);
        return ss;
    }
```

I ran this case 100 times and the average time of `BoundStatement`  was **1.316s** and the average time of `BuiltStatement` was **0.199s**.

Answer (score 0):

I found where **I was wrong**.
When using BuiltStatement, I appended **`limit(1)`** method to fetch only one record. But when using BoundStatement, I didn't append `limit 1` to restrict the returned quantity. In fact, it would return average 100 records. So in this condition, it was slower.